# get old tweets using tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy

How I can use tweepy or any API in java or in Python to get old tweets please.

because I need to retrieve old tweets may be 2 or 2 years old in Arabic to make some treatments using some text processing.

Comment: There are a lot of blog posts and similar detailing how to do this.  Here is one of them: http://knightlab.northwestern.edu/2014/03/15/a-beginners-guide-to-collecting-twitter-data-and-a-bit-of-web-scraping/

Comment: thank's @PatrickHaugh